# Centering four columns of text in a div using CSS flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get these four columns of text centred within the div `bot-col` and equal distances apart. nothing I've found has been the answer so far. Thanks for you help in advance

like this http://www.thehonours.co.uk (at the bottom below the two images)

**html:**

```
<div class="bot-col">
     <div>
      <h2>
        Gift Vouchers
      </h2>
      <p>
        For The Honours - Edinburgh, or any of Martin's other
        great restaurants - Restaurant Martin Wishart and
        Restaurant at Loch Lomond. <a href=
        "gift-vouchers.html">—Purchase here</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>
        Opening Hours
      </h2>
      <p>
        Tuesday - Saturday Lunch 12:00—14:30 Dinner 18:00—22:00
        Closed Sunday all day Closed Monday all day
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>
        Contact Details
      </h2>
      <p>
        <em>The Honours - Edinburgh</em> 58a North Castle
        Street Edinburgh EH2 3LU Telephone 0131 220 2513
        <em><a href=
        "mailto:info@thehonours.co.uk">info@thehonours.co.uk</a></em><br />

        <a href="contact.html">—Find out more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="news_column">
      <h2>
        Newsletter
      </h2>
      <p>
        For all the latest news, updates and events at The
        Honours - Edinburgh, simply enter your details and you
        will receive our exclusive newsletter direct to you
        inbox <a class="newsletter" href="sign-up.html">—Sign
        up</a>
      </p>
        </div>
```

this is what i tried with little success.
**css:**

```
.bot-col{
width: 1192;
height 185;
margin: auto;
display: flex;
text-align: center;
}

.bot-col p{ 
width: 110px;
height: auto;
display: block;
font-size: 7pt;
margin: auto
}
.bot-col h1{
width: 110px;
display: block;
font-size: 14pt;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? I'm kind of confused with your question. https://jsfiddle.net/3zstw6q6/

Comment: Almost, except the columns should be aligned horizontally in the div not vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="bot-col">
    <div style="display: flex;margin: 0 auto;">
        <div>
            <h2>Gift Vouchers</h2>
            <p>
              For The Honour - Edinburgh, or any of Martin's other...
              <a href="gift-vouchers.html">—Purchase here</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using a front-end framework like bootstrap, foundation or skeleton!

It constist just in add into your html some resources and some clases, this classes have properties. You will be able to make rows and then columns inside this rows.

**foundation docs:** http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="large-3 columns article">
      <h2>
        Gift Vouchers
      </h2>
      <p>
        For The Honours - Edinburgh, or any of Martin's other
        great restaurants - Restaurant Martin Wishart and
        Restaurant at Loch Lomond. <a href=
        "gift-vouchers.html">—Purchase here</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns article">
      <h2>
        Opening Hours
      </h2>
      <p>
        Tuesday - Saturday Lunch 12:00—14:30 Dinner 18:00—22:00
        Closed Sunday all day Closed Monday all day
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns article">
      <h2>
        Contact Details
      </h2>
      <p>
        <em>The Honours - Edinburgh</em> 58a North Castle
        Street Edinburgh EH2 3LU Telephone 0131 220 2513
        <em><a href=
        "mailto:info@thehonours.co.uk">info@thehonours.co.uk</a></em><br />

        <a href="contact.html">—Find out more</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns article">
      <h2>
        Newsletter
      </h2>
      <p>
        For all the latest news, updates and events at The
        Honours - Edinburgh, simply enter your details and you
        will receive our exclusive newsletter direct to you
        inbox <a class="newsletter" href="sign-up.html">—Sign
        up</a>
      </p>
</div>
```

**class ="row"** its makes a div telling: I'm gonna put some columns inside.

then, **class ="column"** or **class="columns"** doesn't matter (It's the same).

After it, the large-3 means the width div.

so; every row is grided by 12 columns, then, you can assign the columns you want to every soon-divs but sum of them cannot be over than 12.

After it, u will have a row centered if you add any ID to this row, saying:

```
#idYouWant{
text-align:center;
width: what you want;
}
```

Hope I helped! If not... sorry!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by the "you can assign the columns you want to every soon-divs but sum of them cannot be over than 12."? thank you for explaining these terms it really helps

Comment: oh yes sorry, I don't speak too much english.. :(

Like Foundation says here: **http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html**

This framework permits create a responsive webpage easily creating a div, section, nav or whatever... adding the class="row". AFter that you are telling to the framework you are gonna put inside some fluid content that can change in many devices (small, medium and large).

Then you can give to this interior divs or information inside it (your example blocks) some columns width. and the columns divs sum inside this row cannot be more than 12 in theory.

Comment: Then, u should put the class ="colums" always into the divs inside this row, after that, you are going to put the width by giving some columns range. using the class="large-2 columns" it means this div is gonna have 2 columns as width. in the large devices you can algo say something like:

**<div class="columns small-12 medium-8 large-2>** and is gonna change the div depend the devices. 12 columns on small devices, 8 columns width to the medium and 2 for the large devices.

Comment: **https://jsfiddle.net/u82a6d81/embedded/result/** something like that.

To be able to use this framework you have to download some files in the foundation website (many **.js** and **.css**). and its all :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.bot-col {
  width: 1192px;
  position: relative
}

.bot-col > div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

The second one centers the `<div>` blocks directly *inside* `.bot-col` with the `margin: 20px auto` rule. `auto` applies to left and right nd does the centering, the `20px` can be changed to taste and is the margin above and below the DIVs.

For this centering method to work, the parent element (= `.bot.col`) has to have `position: relative;`  (or absolute or fixed, but *not* in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS `flex` module, you can achieve your layout as follows.

Your `flex` container is `.bot-col`, so you first need `display: flex` and then `justify-content: center` to center the four child blocks in the container.

Finally, set a width value on `.bot-col div`, which is simpler than assign it to the individual elements like `h2` and `p`.

You can set values for width and height if needed.

You can read more about the numerous options for `flex` at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/

**Note:** You might also try `justify-content: space-between` if you want the child block/column elements distributed evenly within the parent block.

```css
.bot-col {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.bot-col div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.bot-col p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7pt;
}
.bot-col h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot-col">
  <div>
    <h2>
        Gift Vouchers
      </h2>
    <p>
      For The Honours - Edinburgh, or any of Martin's other great restaurants - Restaurant Martin Wishart and Restaurant at Loch Lomond. <a href="gift-vouchers.html">—Purchase here</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>
        Opening Hours
      </h2>
    <p>
      Tuesday - Saturday Lunch 12:00—14:30 Dinner 18:00—22:00 Closed Sunday all day Closed Monday all day
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>
        Contact Details
      </h2>
    <p>
      <em>The Honours - Edinburgh</em> 58a North Castle Street Edinburgh EH2 3LU Telephone 0131 220 2513
      <em><a href=
        "mailto:info@thehonours.co.uk">info@thehonours.co.uk</a></em>
      <br />

      <a href="contact.html">—Find out more</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news_column">
    <h2>
        Newsletter
      </h2>
    <p>
      For all the latest news, updates and events at The Honours - Edinburgh, simply enter your details and you will receive our exclusive newsletter direct to you inbox <a class="newsletter" href="sign-up.html">—Sign
        up</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```